# C# Mock concrete class. How?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I want to mock a concrete class, to be specific SortedDictionary.

**Context:**

I have a LocationMapper class defined as below:

```
public class LocationMapper
{
  private SortedDictionary<string, Location>() locationMap;
  public LocationMapper()
  {
    this.locationMap = new SortedDictionary<string, Location>();
  }

  public LocationMapper(SortedDictionary<string, Location> locations)
  {
    this.locationMap = locations;
  }

  public Location AddLocation(Location location)
  {
    if(! locationMap.ContainsKey(location.Name))
    {
      locationMap.Add(location.Name, location)
    }
    return locationMap[location.Name];
  }  
}
```

To Unit Test AddLocation(), I need to Mock the concrete class SortedDictionary<>. Unfortunately, NSubstitute is not allowing it.

```
The unit test that I had envisioned to write is below
[Test]
public void AddLocation_ShouldNotAddLocationAgainWhenAlreadyPresent()
{
  var mockLocationMap = ;//TODO
  //Stub mockLocationMap.ContainsKey(Any<String>) to return "true"
  locationMapper = new LocationMapper(mockLocationMap);
  locationMapper.AddLocation(new Location("a"));
  //Verify that mockLocationMap.Add(..) is not called
}
```

***How would you go about writing Unit Test in this style in DotNet? Or you don't take this path for the known constraints?***

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why mock it? Why not just create an instance and pass it in? You have full control to fill it however you want so I would think you can assert the outcome. If it was an interface then sure mock, but with a concrete dictionary, I don't see it being needed.

Comment: What are you actually testing?  It seems to me that you are actually testing that the SortedDictionary does what it guarantees to do.  What value are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @TyCobb, I've updated the question with my unit testing bias/preference as template unit test case for your perusal.

Comment: *Verify that mockLocationMap.Add(..) is not called* -- Using a concrete instance, add "a" and assert there is 1 item. add "a" again and assert there's still only 1 and it didn't blow up trying to add a duplicate key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to use a unit testing tool that allows you to mock concrete classes, for instance i'm using Typemock Isolator and with it was able to create the test that you wanted to make:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var fakeLocationMap = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SortedDictionary<string, Location>>();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeLocationMap.ContainsKey(string.Empty)).WillReturn(true);

    var instance = new LocationMapper(fakeLocationMap);
    var res = instance.AddLocation(new Location("a"));

    Isolate.Verify.WasNotCalled(() => fakeLocationMap.Add(string.Empty, null));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not mock dictionary here. Actually it's an implementation detail of `LocationMapper` class. And it should be hidden via encapsulation. You might use anything else to store locations - array, list or simple dictionary. It doesn't matter if `LocationMapper` meets its requirements. What are requirements in this case? Something like

> Location mapper should be able to map location which was added to mapper

Currently your mapper is pretty useless and it adds nothing to dictionary behavior. You missing the core - *mapping*. I can only assume how this class is going to be used. You need some public interface for mapping. And test should look like (AutoFixture and FluentAssertions used here):

```
var mapper = new LocationMapper();
var location = fixture.Create<Location>();
mapper.AddLocation(location);
mapper.Map(location.Name).Should().Be(location);
```

While this test is passing you can add locations to mapper and use mapper to map those locations.

Comment: I added code for the context, as I had mentioned in my post. It is not in its entirety :-/

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: If you use VS Enterprise, use Microsoft Fakes to generate a Shim for your class. (ping me if you want a sample)>

If you don't use VS Enterprise (as the majority of people here) you will have to resort to reflection:

```
[Test]
public void AddLocation_ShouldNotAddLocationAgainWhenAlreadyPresent()
{
  var locationMapper = new LocationMapper(mockLocationMap);
  locationMapper.AddLocation(new Location("a"));
  var dict = ((SortedDictionary<string, Location>)typeof(LocationMapper).GetField("locationMap", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(locationMapper));
  Assert.AreEqual("a", dict.FirstOrDefault().Name)
}
```